# Is every colimit-generator dense in an $\infty$-topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-topos-theory

1. Recall that there are various senses in which a full subcategory $G \subseteq C$ may "generate" a category $C$. For example, in order of increasing strength (under reasonable conditions):

   - $G$ is a *generator* if $C \to Fun(G^{op},Set)$ is *faithful*.
   - $G$ is a *strong generator* if $C \to Fun(G^{op},Set)$ is *faithful and conservative*.
   - $G$ is a *colimit-generator* if the smallest full subcategory of $C$ containing $G$ and closed under colimits in $C$, is $C$ itself.
   - $G$ is a *dense generator* if $C \to Fun(G^{op},Set)$ is *fully faithful*.

   Here $C \to Fun(G^{op},Set)$ is the restricted Yoneda functor, $c \mapsto (g \mapsto Hom(g,c))$. See [Mike Shulman's lovely note](https://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/generators.pdf), the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator), or many standard texts for more discussion.
2. Recall also that if $C$ is a Grothendieck topos, then there is a collapse in the hierarchy -- dense generators, colimit-generators, and strong generators all coincide. This is an immediate corollary of Giraud's theorem. [Day and Street](https://doi.org/10.1016%2F0022-4049(86)90065-4) give somewhat more general conditions where this collapse happens. (But it doesn't always happen -- for example, $\mathbb Z$ is a colimit-generator in $Ab$ which is not dense.) **EDIT:** In fact, in a Grothendieck topos, every generator is strong, so the *entire* hierarchy collapses -- but the collapse of the last 3 types happens more generally for quasi-toposes, I believe.

**Question 1:** To what extent is this picture reproduced in $\infty$-categories?

I believe we should still have an analogous hierarchy -- for the notions defined in terms of the functor $C \to Fun(G^{op},Top)$, this is evident, while if $C$ is cocomplete then I think it is straightforward that dense generator $\Rightarrow$ colimit-generator $\Rightarrow$ strong generator. So the question is more about situations where the hierarchy collapses.

The notions of generator which seem to be most commonly used $\infty$-categorically are the strongest ones -- colimit-generators and dense-generators. So I'm particularly interested in these:

**Question 2:** In an $\infty$-topos, is it the case that every colimit-generator is dense?

Comment: Possibly in Question 2, one might have to restrict to hypercomplete $\infty$-toposes to get a positive answer...

Comment: Dumb question: what is the definition of a "faithful" functor between $\infty$-categories?

Comment: @CharlesRezk Good question -- of course, this is not a standard notion! What I have in mind is that $F: C \to D$ is "faithful" if it is a monomorphism in the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories, where "monomorphism" means that $C \times_D C \to C$ is an equivalence. Ayala and Francis [characterize](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04007) (Lemma 5.6) such $F$ as follows: $F$ restricts to a monomorphism of spaces on maximal subgroupoids, and $F: C(c,c') \to D(Fc,Fc')$ is a monomorphism of spaces for each $c,c' \in C$. In turn, a monomorphism of spaces is just an inclusion of path components.

Comment: This is the same as "equivalent to the inclusion of a subcategory", right?

Comment: @DenisNardin I think it's actually "equivalent to the inclusion of a _replete_ subcategory" (a subcategory inclusion which is simultaneously an isofibration). So actually, let me change my mind. A faithful functor $F: C \to D$ should simply be such that $F: C(c,c') \to D(Fc,Fc')$ is a monomorphism of spaces for each $c,c' \in C$.